# Reducing speed of light

Tags: speed-of-light

Can someone explain in lay terms how the research done by Lene Hau about Light speed reduction is actually possible? Isn't the speed of light a constant?

Comment: The question I've linked above specifically references the work of Hau's group.

Answer (score 0):

Speed of light in a vacuum is constant but the speed of light going through different medias is not constant.  The speed of light in other medias is very dependent on the index of refraction.